# How to sync firebase with android room local db?

Tags: firebase, synchronization, android-room, android-jobscheduler, android-workmanager

I have an application that has a remote database(firebase) and local database(room). I get my data from firebase and save it in android room. Also, I use rxjava2 to do that. All posts is get from local database. Everything is okey until here. When I put new child to firebase, it doesnt appear in my application instantly. It is not put in local db. I know that I have to update my remote database every time such as every six hours. I had some researxch to do that. Work Manager and JobScheduler can be used but I dont know how to use that. Is there anyone that give me an advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WorkManager, part of [Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/), is a library by Google, that handle deferrable work that requires a guaranteed execution.

You can read this [blog](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/introducing-workmanager-2083bcfc4712) to see if it covers your requirements. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) is an excellent starting point and there's a codelab that you can do to try the library itself available both in [Java](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/) and [Kotlin](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager-kt/).

WorkManager uses JobScheduler when it runs on API Level 23+, for older Android versions (WorkManager supports API Level 14+) it uses AlarmManager and Broadcast receivers.